# Taylor series of $e^{(x-1)^2}$ about $x=1$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How would we find the Taylor series of $e^{(x-1)^2}$ about $a=1$?

I tried finding the answer using the Taylor series of $e^x$ about $a=1$ which I was able to do correctly. When I substituted $(x-1)^2$ back in for $x$, things went wrong.

Comment: I think you meant $a=1$

Comment: @Ephraim Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n\over n!}\implies e^{\color{blue}{(x-1)^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(\color{blue}{(x-1)^2})^n\over n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(x-1)^{2n}\over n!}$$

Comment: Just to clarify, is this considered centered about x=1 because the series has "x-1" in it? Even though we used the series for e^x centered at x=0?

Comment: Yes. A power series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$ has center $c$. We just use the first series to deduce the second. We don't have to worry about messing up convergence by doing so since $e^x$ has interval of convergence $(-\infty,\infty)$.